# How to save a template as image after giving an input as name in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a app that wishes for person's birthday given the design template for this and I need to enter the name of the person and this might create an image wishing him happy birthday with his name.

I create the textformfield to get the name and I don't how to add my text to the previously created template in flutter.

This is what I tried to get input from user.

```
TextFormField(
                  controller: nametext,
                  autofocus: false,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter name",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                    fillColor: ColorsManager.inputBoxColor,
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: ColorsManager.appColor,
                ),
```

Now how can I use this entered name in some template to convert it to an image to send it to person for birthday wish in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [tapoica](https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca)
library, its great for putting text on top of images,

add this in the pubspec.yaml (under dependencies):

```
dependencies:
  tapioca: ^1.0.5+1
```

in the file where you want to create the image add:

```
import 'package:tapioca/tapioca.dart';
```

if the image is from your assets you will need an additional function to transfer it to pure bytes and write it as a device file

and then afterwards use something like this:

```
import 'package:tapioca/tapioca.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final tapiocaBalls = [
    TapiocaBall.filter(Filters.pink),
    TapiocaBall.imageOverlay(imageBitmap, 300, 300),
    TapiocaBall.textOverlay("birthday person here",100,10,100,Color(0xffffc0cb)),
];
var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path = '${tempDir.path}/path_to_image_here.jpeg';
final cup = Cup(Content(path), tapiocaBalls);
cup.suckUp(path).then((_) {
  print("finish processing");
});
```

than mabye use something like the share plus package to enable sharing the birthday card to social media / messages